# Scroll to Top of Editor Control

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to scroll to the first character of the editor control. Currently when new data is imported into the control, the control scrolls to the bottom which isn't the behavior I want. I don't see a clear way to accomplish this.

This needs to be set at load only as the user needs the ability to type without the cursor jumping to the begging during typing.

[image]

---

The following works for me which I've modified from the answer below. This is set in the Custom Rendered for Android:

```
        protected override void OnVisibilityChanged(global::Android.Views.View changedView, [GeneratedEnum] ViewStates visibility)
    {
        base.OnVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);

        Control.SetSelection(0);
    }
```

Comment: Hi ,could you share an image to explain that ? What is the meaning of new data , whehter is copied from other place ?

Comment: New data being data that is entered programmatically through bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom a **[CustomEditorRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers)** in native solution to achieve that .

**Android** :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace AppEntryTest.Droid
{
    class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        public CustomEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            
            //set position from 0 
            Control.SetSelection(0);

        }
}
```

The effect :

[image]

**iOS** :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace AppEntryTest.iOS
{
    class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.BecomeFirstResponder();

            NSRange range;
            range.Location = 0;
            range.Length = 0;
            Control.SelectedRange = range;
        }

}
```

The effect :

[image]

=============================Update=============================

First , create renderer class in each platform :

[image]

Uesd in Xaml as follow :

```
<Editor Text="{Binding EditorValue}" />
```

In addition , also can create a custom Editor in Forms :

```
public class MyEditor : Editor 
{

}
```

Used in Xaml : `<local:MyEditor Text="{Binding EditorValue}" />`

In rederer class , `assembly` also need to modify to use the custom Editor .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind expanding how I would reference this custom renderer for Android / iOS

Comment: @StevenMarcus Do you mean how to use in Forms ? I have updated answer . About creating Rederer class , you can refer to [Customizing an Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry)

Comment: I cannot use in the property changed section as it constantly moves the cursor. I need it to happen on load only. However I cannot get it to work correctly in the OnElementChanged function

 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            //RUN ON LOAD
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetSelection(0);

                Control.ScrollTo(0, 0);


            }

            
        }

Comment: NVM got it. Updated the question above. Thanks for the help @Junior Jiang - MSFT